# DDB table not updating all items

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am running the below python code from Linux terminal which would run to insert the "Time" and "Message" of 5K items in the dummy_table. First few executions inserted all the items fine, once the table reached 50K items, the next set of executions are not inserting all the expected 5K items in the table only few 100 are getting updated.

### Code:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-2')
table_bms = dynamodb.Table('dummy_table')

def update_tables():
    try:
        eastern = dateutil.tz.gettz('US/Eastern')
        with table_bms.batch_writer() as writer:
            for i in range(5000):
                msg = f"counter {i}"                
                writer.put_item(Item={"Time": datetime.datetime.now(tz=eastern).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %Z'), "Message": msg})

    except ClientError as err:
        print(
            "Couldn't load data into table %s. Here's why: %s: %s",
            err.response["Error"]["Code"],
            err.response["Error"]["Message"],
        )
```

Can anyone suggest if anyone had faced similar problems in the past.?

Comment: What is your primary key for DynamoDB?

Comment: The most common reason for "I wrote N items without error but I only see K items in my database (where K < N)" is that some of the writes *replaced* existing items.

Comment: Here the primary key is 'Time'.
It doesn't seems replaced as when i run the code for the first couple to times (3-4 times), i am able to scan the count which shows the number items in the table. But, after the table has reached a certain size, it just doesn't add/skips to add any more items to the table.
 For example:  First run inserts (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), 
Second run inserts same..until 4th run. But after the 5th run it just adds (4,6,8) the other items seems to go missing from the table.